# Managing Stops for Pyramid Orders Individually

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking for a way to directly manage pyramid orders individually. I tried using strategy.position_entry_name function but apparently it only references the earliest open trade.

For example, in the script below I would want to do what I did for the stop of LONG 1 to LONG 2 and 3. I could theoretically use strategy.opentrades to reference them, but this seems unreliable as when a situation where LONG 1 is stopped and LONG 2 and 3 are still open, LONG 3 will open again as the open trades drops from 3 to 2. Ideally, I would want the code to directly recognize it is still holding LONG 3 so it should not open it again.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
//@version=4
strategy("Manage Pyramid Stop Orders Individually", shorttitle='MPSOI' , overlay=true, pyramiding=3)

MA = sma(close, 50)

Buy = MA > MA[1]
Sell = MA < MA[1]

PositionSize = strategy.initial_capital/close
Stops = low

//LONG STOPS
Long1InPosition = strategy.position_entry_name == 'LONG 1'
Long1_Stops = Stops
Long1_Stops := Long1InPosition ? Long1_Stops[1] : low

Long2InPosition = strategy.position_entry_name == 'LONG 2'
Long2_Stops = Stops
Long2_Stops := Long2InPosition ? Long2_Stops[1] : low

Long3InPosition = strategy.position_entry_name == 'LONG 3'
Long3_Stops = Stops
Long3_Stops := Long3InPosition ? Long3_Stops[1] : low


if strategy.opentrades == 0
    strategy.entry("LONG 1", strategy.long, qty=PositionSize, when=Buy)

if strategy.opentrades == 1
    strategy.entry("LONG 2", strategy.long, qty=PositionSize, when=Buy)

if strategy.opentrades == 2
    strategy.entry("LONG 3", strategy.long, qty=PositionSize, when=Buy)


strategy.exit("LONG 1 Exit", 'LONG 1', stop=Long1_Stops)
strategy.exit("LONG 2 Exit", 'LONG 2', stop=Long2_Stops)
strategy.exit("LONG 3 Exit", 'LONG 3', stop=Long3_Stops)

strategy.close_all(when=Sell)
strategy.cancel_all(when=Sell)


//PLOTS
MAcolor = Buy ? color.lime : Sell ? color.red : color.gray
plot(MA, color=MAcolor, title='MA', linewidth=3)
plot(Long1_Stops, color=color.red, title='Long1_Stop', style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Long2_Stops, color=color.maroon, title='Long2_Stop', style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(Long3_Stops, color=color.purple, title='Long3_Stop', style=plot.style_linebr)

bgcolor(Long1InPosition ? color.lime : na)
bgcolor(Long2InPosition ? color.olive : na)
bgcolor(Long3InPosition ? color.teal : na)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `strategy.order` instead of `strategy.entry` and `strategy.exit`.

Note that using strategy.order means that pyramiding settings have no effect and you have to manage the pyramiding effect yourself.